# How to modify so that links with specific class value trigger popup function with JavaScript/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I need to "modify the popups.js and the popups.html files so that only links with a specific class value trigger the createPopup() function." How do I got about doing this? I'm a complete beginner learning javascipt and I have no idea what it's asking for and how to do this.

```js
/*Modify popups.js and .html so that only links with a specific class value 
trigger the createPopup() function*/

function createPopup(e) {
    'use strict';
    
    // Get the event object:
    if (typeof e == 'undefined') var e = window.event;

    // Get the event target:
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

    // Create the window:
    var popup = window.open(target.href, 'PopUp', 'height=100,width=100,top=100,left=100,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
    
    // Give the window focus if it's open:
    if ( (popup !== null) && !popup.closed) {
        popup.focus();
        return false; // Prevent the default behavior.
    } else { // Allow the default behavior.
        return true;
    }
    
} // End of createPopup() function.

// Establish functionality on window load:
window.onload = function() {
    'use strict';
    
    // Add the click handler to each link:
    for (var i = 0, count = document.links.length; i < count; i++) {
        document.links[i].onclick = createPopup;
    } // End of for loop.

}; // End of onload function.
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Popup Windows</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Script 9.4 - popups.html -->
    <p><a href="popupB.html" id="link" target="PopUp">B Link</a> (Will open in a new window.)</p>
    <p><a href="popupA.html" id="link" target="PopUp">A Link</a> (Will open in a new window.)</p>
    <script src="js/popups.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.links[i].onclick = createPopup;
```

That line should become something like:

```
var link = document.links[i]
if (link.classList.contains('link'))
   document.links[i].onclick = createPopup;
```

---

Of course you need to update your HTML:

```
<a href="popupB.html" id="link" target="PopUp">
```

1. ID's should only appear once in the HTML (your `<a>` each have the same ID)
2. Change your `id` to `class` to fix that:

   ```
   <a href="popupB.html" class="link" target="PopUp">
   ```

---

## Full Code

```js
/*Modify popups.js and .html so that only links with a specific class value 
trigger the createPopup() function*/

function createPopup(e) {
  'use strict';
  
  // Get the event object:
  if (typeof e == 'undefined') var e = window.event;

  // Get the event target:
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

  // Create the window:
  var popup = window.open(target.href, 'PopUp','height=100,width=100,top=100,left=100,location=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');

  if (!popup)
    console.log('Error:', "popup doesn't exist");

  // Give the window focus if it's open:
  if (popup && (popup !== null) && !popup.closed) {
    popup.focus();
    return false; // Prevent the default behavior.
  } else { // Allow the default behavior.
    return true;
  }

} // End of createPopup() function.

// Establish functionality on window load:
window.onload = function() {
  'use strict';

  // Add the click handler to each link:
  for (var i = 0, count = document.links.length; i < count; i++) {
    var link = document.links[i];
    if (link.classList.contains('link')){
       link.onclick = createPopup;
       }
  } // End of for loop.

}; // End of onload function.
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Popup Windows</title>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Script 9.4 - popups.html -->
  <p><a href="popupB.html" class="link" target="PopUp">B Link</a> (Will open in a new window.)</p>
  <p><a href="popupA.html" class="link" target="PopUp">A Link</a> (Will open in a new window.)</p>
  <script src="js/popups.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can add a specific class to those link which will trigger pop up.

Change the HTML , remove the duplicate `id` & add a common class

```
<p><a href="popupB.html" id="link_1" class = 'pop' target="PopUp">B Link</a> (Will open in a new window.)</p>

<p><a href="popupA.html" id="link_2" class = "pop" target="PopUp">A Link</a> (Will open in a new window.)</p>
```

Now you cna use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get the elements with specific class. You can also you `document.getElementsByClassName`

var getLink = document.querySelectorAll('.pop')

Then use the loop to add event to it

```
for (var i = 0, count = getLink.length; i < count; i++) {
        getLink[i].onclick = createPopup;
    }
```

Not tested , but you can give a try. Hope this snippet will be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use className property of dom for checking the class name that need to trigger popup function

```
for (var i = 0, count = document.links.length; i < count; i++) {
    if(document.links[i].className=="required_className")
     document.links[i].onclick = createPopup;
}
```